# An error has occured! Seems pip doesn't seem to work

Tags: kali-linux, pip

I tried to install Storm-Breaker on Kali linux but when I run my ./install it says that the requirement file is invalid although installe, and also displays pip not working despite being in the latest version. I executed the `./install` which purpose is to install the Storm-Breaker onto my Kali Linux, runned file as root.

This is what i runned:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

it worked and then I also tried installing the `install.sh` like this:

```
sudo bash install.sh
```

`ERROR: Invalid requirement: "./requirement.txt" Hint: It looks like a path. The path does exist The argument you provided (./requirement.txt) seems to be a requirement file. If in that case, use the "-r" flag to install the packages specified within it. An error has occured! Seems pip doesn't work`

Github page Followed:
https://github.com/ultrasecurity/Storm-Breaker/blob/main/README.md

Comment: You've not told us anything about the tool you're trying to install. Neither have you told us about the things you've already tried to fix it. Is the tool already available as a package you can just download? If it's not specifically related to pentesting and security you would probably be better installing it on a more general purpose distribution rather than the specialist Kali

Comment: Can you provide more information about `install.sh` (content, purpose, if you execute it as root or not, etc.)

Comment: @ChrisDavies I did like it told me and I used the -r flag when installing the requirements file. It still displays the same problem

Comment: Did the install script generate the error message you've shown us? What _exactly_ have you run as part of the [installation instructions](https://github.com/ultrasecurity/Storm-Breaker#readme) for Storm Breaker?

Comment: In the instructions, you are not told to run `./install`.  Please update your question with the exact commands that led up to the issue.

Comment: @ChrisDavies I'm not a Python person, but [this line in the script](https://github.com/ultrasecurity/Storm-Breaker/blob/2402dbe055710977ede3b39d369e3503b8469b06/install.sh#L177C21-L177C21) seems to have a bug (using an option as an argument to `-r`).

Comment: @Kusalananda I know that in the instructions, is not written to run `./install` but from the instructions on Github is clearly specified to run this. Sorry for not providing the Github page earlier.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

In the above image(I took a screenshot of it from the GitHub repo you shared in your question), The Installation instruction shows that the creator has mentioned the command `sudo python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt`, so it indicates that he's suggesting to use `python3-pip` not `python2-pip`. So to overcome the issue you are facing with requirements, you need to install `python3-pip`, you can do the same by using this command in CLI/terminal: `sudo apt install python3-pip -y`, after installing it, try running this command: `sudo pip3 install -r requirements.txt`, I hope this will resolve your issue. Feel free to ask again for help if you face the same or any other problem.

Edit: There can also be permissions conflicts that are preventing the requirements from being installed, try this command after Cd into the cloned folder: `chmod +x *`, this command will give executable permissions to all files present in that cloned folder.

Edit2: I cloned this repo myself and tested it, I faced the same error, however, I have fixed that, You can clone this repo from my GitHub repository and follow the steps I've mentioned in the README.md file. Here's the [link](https://github.com/Atuls-git/Storm-Breaker) to my repo. I've also opened a pull request to the original owner's repo, I hope he'll accept my merge request.

Comment: -1 for the action suggested in the last paragraph. `chmod +x *` is never a correct solution

Comment: @ChrisDavies Please have a look at 2nd edit.

Answer (score -3):

The error you received states that you actually runned
`pip install -r ./requirement.txt` (`ERROR: Invalid requirement: "./requirement.txt"`). The error also tells us that the file does not exist which seems to make sense when looking at the git repo (`The path does exist`).

The file on github is called `requirements.txt`. Try running

```
pip install -r ./requirements.txt
```

instead and it should work.

Comment: Note that this is a command that the user says they ran and which worked. What did not work was running the `install.sh` script as mentioned in the instructions. This could be due to a bug in the `install.sh` script.

Comment: Oh yea you are right, I must have overread that. I did some digging and the line you found in the install script actually looks wrong. From what I found the requirement file has to be the argument immediately after `-r` (or `--requirement`). So the fix would probably be changing that line to `env python3 -m pip install --break-system-packages -r ./requirements.txt`